# "lots of knowledge" "lots of techniques"

Tags: word-usage

When I said "experts bring us lots of knowledge and techniques", a native speaker told me

> lots of knowledge is ok, but lots of techniques doesn't work, we have to use a countable noun

[image]

As per Cambridge Dictionary ["knowledge"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/knowledge) is [ S or U ], ["technique"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/technique?q=techniques) is also [ S or U ]

what is the correct usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To begin with, "lots of knowledge" is quite informal. A more formal way to say it would be "a lot of knowledge", "much knowledge" etc.

Now, "lots of techniques" is *even more* informal. You will hear native speakers say this kind of thing, but it's not technically correct. "Many techniques" is a better choice.

Comment: Thank you. "much knowledge" indicates that "knowledge" here is uncountable while "many techniques" indicates that "techniques" is countable, right?

Comment: People, esp of non-native, have a tendency to use 'a lot of' and 'lots of' interchangeably. Agree with @Steve Bennett that 'a lot of' is better and formal.